# Matrix Polynomial with Non-Zero Coefficients

Tags: matrices

Let $A ∈ M_{n \times n}(F)$ for some field $F$. Prove there is some non-zero polynomial
$p(x)$ such that $p(A) = 0$.

I approached this question by dealing with each entry of the matrix and equating it to the respective $0$ on the $0$ matrix but I am stuck now as to what I should do next. Also the question does not allow the use of Cayley Hamilton Theorem.

Comment: Related: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Hamilton_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I,A,A^{2},...,A^{n^{2}+1}$ cannot all be linearly independent because the dimension of the space of $n \times n$ matrices is $n^{2}$. Hence, some non-trivial linear combnation of these must vanish.

Comment: Thanks ! Makes lot of sense